Add text in an image in a specific coordinates with SwiftUI
I want to add multiple text inside an image with specific coordinates relative to the image. Text size can vary. I am using kingfisher to load the image.
I have tried with position x, y coordinates with ZStack. but it's not working accoding to my expectations.

See How to set text position for all screen sizes in SwiftUI?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Try this approach using GeometryReader and SpatialTapGesture, as shown
in the basic example code, to add/move some text at the tapped position.
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var location = CGPoint(x: 111, y: 111)
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            GeometryReader { proxy in
                Image(systemName: "globe").resizable()
                    .frame(width: 333, height: 333)
                    .background(.blue.opacity(0.3))
                    .gesture(SpatialTapGesture()
                        .onEnded{ tap in
                            print("----> tap: \(tap)")
                            location = tap.location
                        })
                
                Text("More text")
                    .position(x: location.x, y: location.y)
                    .foregroundStyle(.red)
            }
        }
    }
}


did my answer not worked for you?
